# V4 e V7 no Android

Tags: android, app-compat-v7

Por que em alguns exemplos na internet, encontramos algo assim:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>

<android.support.v7.view.ViewPager/>
```

O que seria esse V4 e V7?

E neste exemplo,

```
android.support.design.widget
```

O que seria este support?

Comment: Creio que seja a "versão".

Answer (score 4):

Em resumo, são as **Bibliotecas de Suporte** do Android.

O Android possui [inúmeras versões](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hist%C3%B3rico_de_vers%C3%B5es_do_Android), e em cada nova versão é criado novas APIs. Porém, o seu aplicativo, geralmente, não é desenvolvido apenas para a versão mais nova. Com isso, a Google possui o [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html).

#### v4 Support Libraries

Segundo a Google, é:

> These libraries are designed to be used with Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher. They include the largest set of APIs compared to the other libraries, including support for application components, user interface features, accessibility, data handling, network connectivity, and programming utilities.

Em tradução, essas bibliotecas são projetadas para serem usadas com o Android 2.3 (API 9) e superior. Elas incluem o maior número de API's em comparação com as demais bibliotecas.

Para entender melhor o que ela contempla, veja a [referência do pacote](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html)

#### v7 Support Libraries

Segundo a Google, é:

> This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design pattern. This library includes support for material design user interface implementations.

Em tradução, essa biblioteca adiciona suporte para implementações do [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html).

Algumas das classes principais inclusas são:

- [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)
- [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)
- [AppCompatDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html)
- [ShareActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html)

Dentre outras, como:

- [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)
- [GrisLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html)
- [MediaRouter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.html)
- [Outras...](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-palette)

> Devo ressaltar que a library v7 depende da library v4.

#### Mais Supports Libbrarys

Além das librarys citadas acima, o Google possui várias outras para auxiliar o desenvolvimento, como:

- [v8 Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v8)
- [v13 Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v13)
- [v14 Preference Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v14-preference)
- [v17 Preference Support Library for TV](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v17-preference)
- [v17 Leanback Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback)
- [Annotations Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#annotations)
- [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#design)
- [Custom Tabs Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#custom-tabs)
- [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent)
- [App Recommendation Support Library for TV](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#recommendation)

Para maiores detalhes, você pode verificar o [Support Library Revision History](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) da Google.

Comment: Mas se eu definir no Android, que a versão minima para rodar meu App é a 5, logo, utilizar as mesmas não fazem sentindo?

Comment: @Luhhh Se tudo que você necessita está na [versão 5 (API: 21) do Android](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) e não terá compatibilidade com versões inferiores, não precisa utilizar.

Comment: @Luhhh Mas é bom ressaltar que a Google já possui mais duas versões do Android acima da 5.

Answer (score 1):

> O que seria esse V4 e V7?

Apesar da documentação actual dizer que ambas são para serem usadas a partir da versão 2.3(API 9), a razão da notação `Vnn` era indicar a qual versão do SDK ela é retro-compatível<sup>(1)</sup>.

Assim, `V4` indica que pode ser usada em dispositivos *Android 1.6+(API Level 4+)* e a `V7` em *Android 2.1+(API Level 7+)*.

Não sei se a razão da alteração da documentação é apenas por haver agora muito poucos dispositivos com Android 1.6 e 2.1 e eles não serem compatíveis com a Google Play Store, ou é porque realmente a compatibilidade é apenas a partir da 2.3.

> O que seria este support?

*Support*, em inglês, quer dizer suportar, apoiar, ajudar.

`android.support.design.widget` é o *package name* onde se encontram alguns dos *widget* do *Material Design* que podem ser usados em versões anteriores ao Android 5.

Ele existe na *Android Design Support Library* cuja função é permitir que dispositivos com versões Android inferiores à 5 **"suportem"** o *Material Design*.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> - Não consegui recuperar a documentação antiga mas existem respostas no SOen que contêm [excertos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271529/2556111) ou *experts* como o [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749667/2556111) que o confirmam.</sub>

<sub>Note que `android.support.v7.view.ViewPager` não existe.</sub>

Comment: Eu li essa resposta, mas como a documentação mostrava algo diferente, eu entendi que algo foi alterado para não funcionar mai, mas se funciona, devo desculpas ao @LeonardoDias, pois a documentação falava algo diferente. Mas, ótima resposta

Comment: @Randrade A razão da notação V4 e V7 é aquela que dei na resposta. Se as bibliotecas continuam a ser compatíveis com essas versões não sei, mas julgo que sim. É uma questão de testar.